# Issues with xml in sql server 2012

Tags: xml, sql-server-2012

I would like to be able to use an output from a SQL query as a parameter in a XML query in SQL Server 2012.  Here is an example.

```
Declare @xml = (Select uniqueTaxID, taxName 
                from Taxes 
                where orderGroup = @someNumber 
                for xml path('Tax'), root('Taxes'))
```

The expected output will give me all the applicable taxes for an order.  There could be 1 tax, or several.

Example output:

```
<Taxes>
    <Tax>
        <uniqueTaxID>1</uniqueTaxID>
        <taxName>Some Tax</taxName>
    </Tax>
    <Tax>
        <uniqueTaxID>2</uniqueTaxID>
        <taxName>Some Other Tax</taxName>
    </Tax>
</Taxes>
```

Now I have another simple SQL query

```
Select taxID, someItem, @xml.query('
    for $i in Taxes/Tax/uniqueTaxID
    return Taxes/Tax/taxName
    ') from someGroupOfItems
```

Unfortunately the way it is written, I will get both `<taxName>` elements. I need this to be dynamic. If `taxID` was 1, then I want my XML query to return `Some Tax`, and if it was 2 then it would return `Some Other Tax`.

I tried:

```
Select taxID, someItem, @xml.query('
    for $i in Taxes/Tax/uniqueTaxID
    where $i = ' + taxID + '
    return $i')
```

But that gave me the error

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal.

If I type the number in directly it works fine, so I know that it has something to do with my concatenating the string

Comment: Is there a reason to do this with using XML? Why not just use an outer join between the tables in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [sql:column()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx) to access a value from a table in the XQuery expression and you can use [value()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx) to extract a single value from the XML.

```sql
select T.taxID,
       @xml.value('(
                   for $i in /Taxes/Tax
                   where $i/uniqueTaxID = sql:column("T.TaxID")
                   return $i/taxName
                   )[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as taxName
from someGroupOfItems as T
```

You can also do the same without the FLOWR.

```sql
select T.taxID,
       @xml.value('(/Taxes/Tax[uniqueTaxID = sql:column("T.TaxID")]/taxName)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as taxName
from someGroupOfItems as T
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I really understand what you're trying to do - are you trying to extract the value of the `<taxName>` element from the XML that you have, based on a given `taxID` value?

If so - then try something like this (with your `@XML` variable as input):

```
DECLARE @TaxID INT = 1

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        UniqueTaxID = TaxNode.value('(uniqueTaxID)[1]', 'int'),
        TaxName = TaxNode.value('(taxName)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
    FROM 
        @XML.nodes('/Taxes/Tax') AS XTbl(TaxNode)
)
SELECT TaxName
FROM CTE
WHERE UniqueTaxID = @TaxID
```

I basically "shred" the XML back into relational data in the CTE (Common Table Expression) and then extract the appropriate `TaxName` value from it, based on the `@TaxID`.

This really begs the question: why on earth are you converting to XML in the first place, if you want to get back relational values in the end from that XML ..... seems like an utterly unnecessary detour....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of what marc_s suggested that might answer the "use an output from an SQL query" part of your question more directly. The values of UniqueTaxID to retrieve (1 and 3) are in a table here.

```
declare @xml XML = N'<Taxes>
    <Tax>
        <uniqueTaxID>1</uniqueTaxID>
        <taxName>Some Tax</taxName>
    </Tax>
    <Tax>
        <uniqueTaxID>2</uniqueTaxID>
        <taxName>Some Other Tax</taxName>
    </Tax>
    <Tax>
        <uniqueTaxID>3</uniqueTaxID>
        <taxName>Third Tax</taxName>
    </Tax>
</Taxes>';

WITH someGroup(taxID) AS (
  SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3
), Tax(uniqueTaxID,taxName) AS (
  SELECT
    x.value('(uniqueTaxID)[1]', 'int'),
    x.value('(taxName)[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  FROM @xml.nodes('/Taxes/Tax') as X(x) 
)
  SELECT
    g.taxID,
    t.taxName
  FROM Tax AS t
  JOIN someGroup AS g
  ON g.taxID = t.uniqueTaxID
```